# Java Exception Handling understanding issue

Tags: java, exception, arithmeticexception

I'm not able to understand this program. I expect it to output "Hello World", but instead it prints only the "World".  I thought that first the `try` block would execute, printing "Hello" and " ", then afterward when it encounters a `1/0`, it would throw an `ArithmeticException`.  The exception would be caught by `catch` block, then "World" would be printed.

The program is as follows.

```
 import java.util.*;
 class exception{
     public static void main(String args[]) 
     {
         try
         {
             System.out.println("Hello"+" "+1/0);
         } 
         catch(ArithmeticException e) 
         {
             System.out.println("World");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think it would print `"Hello"` before evaluating `1/0`?

Comment: It has to interpret the value of `"Hello" + " " + 1/0` before it prints anything. `"Hello"` isn't printed because you aren't saying to print _just_ `"Hello"`, rather `"Hello"` plus something that causes the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `"Hello"+" "+1/0` will be evaluated. And then passed as an argument to `System.out.println(...)`. That's why an exception is thrown before `System.out.println(...)` would have been called.

Answer (score 5):

The exception is thrown before calling the `println` function. The argument value has to be calculated before the function call.

In order for your program to achieve the results you expect, you would edit the code in the `try` block as follows:

```
     try
     {
         // this will work and execute before evaluating 1/0
         System.out.print("Hello ");
         // this will throw the exception
         System.out.print(1/0);
     } 
     catch(ArithmeticException e) 
     {
         System.out.println("World");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not simply scan the "words" left to right. Everything inside the `( )` needs to be evaluated successfully, and if it is then it gets printed.

It looks at "Hello" and it's fine.
Next it looks at 1/0 and creates error.

In the event that the math evaluated successfully it would attempt to concatenate "Hello" and the result. And if that was successful, then it would be printed.

Comment: Understood sir. really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments that are passed in println function/method will be checked first followed by calling of println.So , exception will rise before calling println.Since exception is raised control will go to catch and only "World" will be printed

Answer (score 1):

It will checked statement by statement. So, it checks for whole println argument. But, it has an exception, so goes for executing catch block.

NOTE: If it execute first half statement and than checks for Exception, no need remains for try-catch block.